# Lebesgue measure on set difference

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

While studying a book on measure theoretic probability (by KR Parthasarthy), I came across a proof which employs the following equality:

$
L((A + x) \Delta (A + y)) = L(A \Delta [A + (y - x)])
$

where $L$ is the Lebesgue measure on real line.

I am not able to see how this equality holds. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A+x$ is the set $A$ translated by $x$, and $A+y$ is the set $A+(y-x)$ translated by $x$, so $(A+x)\mathop{\triangle}(A+y)$ is just the set $A\mathop{\triangle}\big(A+(y-x)\big)$ translated by $x$. Translation preserves Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it now!

Comment: @Tanay: You’re welcome!